# Are typescript type definitions required?

Tags: typescript

My understanding of typescript definition files is that they are used to provide tooling support and are not required to compile typescript.

However given the following:

*app.ts*

```
import {Observable} from 'rx';

Observable
    .interval(1000)
    .subscribe(n => console.log(n));
```

Running:

```
npm install typescript rx --save
.\node_modules\.bin\tsc app.ts --module commonjs
```

Gives the error:

```
app.ts(1,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rx'.
```

Import the type definitions for rx fixes this

*app.ts*

```
/// <reference path="./node_modules/rx/ts/rx.all.d.ts" />

import {Observable} from 'rx';

Observable
    .interval(1000)
    .subscribe(n => console.log(n));
```

**Questions**

- It appears that the definition files are required, is this always the case?
- The rx npm package includes the definition files. Can typescript automatically search the node modules folder to find them without me having to explicitly reference them?

---

### Update

basarat was correct about the `typings` property. See [Typings for npm packages](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Typings-for-npm-packages) for more information

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It appears that the definition files are required, is this always the case?

No. If the module does it properly using the `typings` property it would *just work*. More: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/nodejs.html

> The rx npm package includes the definition files. Can typescript automatically search the node modules folder to find them without me having to explicitly reference them?

Only if they have `typings` setup properly ... which they don't.

Comment: Hmmm.. this does not seem to be the case with angular2. I may be mistaken, but the angular2 npm package does not require you to import the type definition however it's package.json file does not have the typings property. Am I missing something?

Comment: If you do `'angular2'` it will not work. However they ship with `angular2.d.ts` in the *root* of the package hence `angular2/angular2` *does work*

Comment: I still don't understand why typings are required. What if a package doesn't include its typings and there's no existing definition anywhere? I thought types in TypeScript were optional but it seems you cannot use a package without its typings...

Comment: @basarat This is also requires `"moduleResolution": "node"` typescript compiler option.

Comment: @emzero, have you got your answer since?