# What are typings in typescript?

Tags: typescript, angular

I am trying to learn angular 2 with typescript and want to know why and how is this typings file created and used ?

In my project folder I have a typings folder which is generated and file called index.d.ts. I have gone through the documentation of typescript and cant seem to understand why it is needed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are typescript typings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34590168/what-are-typescript-typings)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typings describes contract of libraries you use. This allows the TypeScript compiler that what you use exist (classes, properties, ...).

You can install typings from a repository using the `typings` command or let the compiler find out them leveraging the strategy specified in the `tsconfig.json` file with the `moduleResolution` attribute.

For Angular2, they (`.d.ts` files) are resolved within the `node_modules/@angular` folder since the framework contains its typings. For other libraries, like Lodash, it's not the case. So you need to install them from the repository.

To define a typings file you can leverage the `export declare class` clause:

```
export declare class SomeClass {
  name: String;
  constructor(name?: String);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `typings` folder and the `index.d.ts` are managed by a type definition package manager called [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) or possibly its predecessor [tsd](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd).

For third-party libraries that do not ship with their own type definitions, the [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) package manager is used to install those type definitions into your project.