# Must I install typings when writing code in Visual Studio 2013 in TypeScript?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, visual-studio-2013

**THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE !!**

Some people marked this post as duplicate, however **I WAS NOT ABLE** to find the resolution in those posts.

This post is related to VS2013 and it's INABILITY to build TypeScript project **without typings**.

I have VS2013 "MVC/WebAPI 2.0/AngularJS/TypeScript" Project, where I use Nuget to pull all required packages. If I dont install typings, the project doesnt build. This makes no sense to me.

Here, I decided to uninstall all typings from my VS project... **and TypeScript stopped working (wouldn't compile)**

typings are for Intellisense... why do I get TypeScript build errors?

> Error  1   Cannot find name 'angular'.
>   Error   8   Cannot find namespace 'ng'.
>   Error   27  Cannot find name 'toastr'.

and so on....

[image][image]

Comment: You'll probably want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/37099577/215552

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are typescript type definitions required?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34169314/are-typescript-type-definitions-required)

Comment: Its not a duplicate because my question is related to Visual Studio typescript support, which is different from non-VS